# Expected "]" in method called from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call a method in my AppDelegate class using the following code. The compiler is showing an "Expected ]" error, no matter how many ] characters I put in.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
[[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] authenticateUser(usernameField.text, passwordField.text)]];
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the first and last bracket since they have no purpose?

Comment: its not the extra brackets but you probably didn't close a bracket at some other point of your app

Comment: As a side note. Don't put code like this in your app delegate. You should (at the very least) create a Singleton class called something like `UserManager`. It's bad practise to put code like this in the app delegate.

Comment: You don't even need a singleton - a helper class that has this as a static method will work just as well.

Comment: u mix method passing with function calling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the code has the app delegate trying to call a function, not a method.

```
[[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] authenticateUser(usernameField.text, passwordField.text)]];
```

rewriting (and removing the extra `[]`:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

[appDelegate authenticateUser(usernameField.text, passwordField.text)];
```

We see that while appDelegate expects a method it finds a function.

Change `authenticateUser` to be a method.
Ex:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
[appDelegate authenticateUser:usernameField.text pass:passwordField.text];
```